# iOS UIStepper not functioning properly

Tags: ios, ipad, uistepper

Some simple code:

```
- (IBAction)Up_Down:(UIStepper *)sender {
     double value = [sender value];
     [NumDayLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", (int)value]];
}
```

It *partially* works.

I start it out at five. If I press +, nothing happens. If I press + again, it goes to 6. Then it will continue going up by one each time I press +. Now, if I press + until it reaches 9, then I hit minus, it goes to 10. Then I hit minus again and it goes to 9, then will continue back down so long as I keep pressing minus. If I bring it down to 3, then hit plus, it will go to 2, then start going up so long as I keep pressing +. Hopefully, you get the idea.

Comment: What event is the action being triggered for? Since you are always one value behind it sounds like you may have added the action for `UIControlEventTouchUpInside`. The correct event is `UIControlEventValueChanged`

Comment: You hit the nail on the head. Please post this as an answer so I can give you credit.

Comment: Except, actually, that I had it on TouchDown, not TouchUpInside.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are always one value behind it sounds like you may have added the action for `UIControlEventTouchUpInside`. It fires before the stepper value has changed. The correct event for a UIStepper is `UIControlEventValueChanged`.